# Lottery Combinations Question

Tags: combinations

Background: The Daily 3 game is a daily game. It consists of three sets of balls, each numbered from 0 through 8 (9 is omitted due to its visual similarity to
6). One ball is drawn from each set giving a 3-digit winning number.
All numbers must be in the correct order to win.

Question: How many different combinations are possible with the Daily 3
game?

Answer:
This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure if I'm correct:
24!/(24-3)! = 12144

12144 combinations

Answer (score 2):

There are 9 choices for the first number, 9 choices for the second number, and 9 choices for the third number. Using the multiplication principle, the total number of combinations is $9^3=729$.